# Facebook Page Tab not showing on a PC

Tags: windows, facebook, tabs

I have created a couple of apps to show on my companies facebook page. I have tested every browser on my mac and everything is working as its supposed to. However, it will not work on any browser on a Windows machine. I have inputted both the page tab url as well as the secure page tab url so I am confused as to why it will not show up on a PC.

Here is think to one of my page tabs:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Atria-Senior-Living/208728162501220?id=208728162501220&sk=app_131012823749816

I have searched all over and cant find any solutions to this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what was going on. I did not have "www" listed after "https://". For whatever reason the Windows machine did not like that.